# Filling a region between two straight lines

Tags: plotting, regions, filling

I want to fill the region between two straight lines without displaying the region boundaries. How can it be done?

> ContourPlot[{x == 2, x == 4}, {x, -2, 8}, {y, -2, 6}]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BoundaryStyle -> None` as shown [in the documentation of `RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html):

```
RegionPlot[2 <= x <= 4, {x, -2, 8}, {y, -2, 6}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Roman. It's working.

Comment: Just saw your answer after I updated.

Answer (score 3):

is this what you mean?

```
p1 = ContourPlot[{x == 2, x == 4}, {x, -2, 8}, {y, -2, 6}];
r = ImplicitRegion[2 < x < 4 && -2 < y < 6, {x, y}];
p2 = RegionPlot[r];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

In this case, just plot the region directly. No need for `ContourPlot` at all to be there.

```
r = ImplicitRegion[2 < x < 4 && -2 < y < 6, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[r, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 8}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, @Nasser for your answer. You are almost close. I just don't want the border lines surrounding the region.

Comment: @SahabubJahedi fyi, updated

Comment: Thanks, @Nasser, it's working.

Answer (score 2):

```
c := RandomInteger[{-100, 100}];

RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[
  HalfPlane[{{2, c}, {2, c}}, {1, 0}]
  , HalfPlane[{{4, c}, {4, c}}, {-1, 0}]
  ]
 , Frame -> True
 , BoundaryStyle -> None
 , PlotRange -> { {-2, 8}, {-2, 6}}
 ]
```

[image]